# /bin directory in Xubuntu 18.04

Tags: xubuntu

I installed Xubuntu 18.04, and in the /bin directory the executable are recognized as a shared library file. Why is this?.

Thanks.

[bin directory screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CfKdK.png)

Comment: Can you please [edit](https://askubuntu.com/posts/1047774/edit) your question and copy and paste the output of what you are seeing that is showing that the `/bin` executables are being seen as a shared library?  Thank you!

Comment: Attached a link with a screenshot. Thanks!

Comment: That doesn't seem to be `/bin`.

Comment: I'm sorry, I edited the attached image.

Comment: I don't see any shared libraries there. Based on the icons, there are text files, executables, and symlinks.

Comment: Thanks
I agree, but in: Properties / File type, executables are recognized as a shared library file.

Comment: Possibly this bug [file mis-identifies modern executables as application/x-sharedlib](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/file/+bug/1747711) - although it is reported against the `file` utility, filemanagers use the same `libmagic-mgc` under the hood AFAIK

Comment: @Yrobel OK, then the screenshot doesn't add any useful info.